How to use the Plot[] when the x-range is very narrow?
I need to plot some function, say Log[x], in a very narrow range of x:  1-10^-n <= 1+10^-n, where n > 13. The command
Plot[Log[x],{x,1-10^-n,1+10^-n},WorkingPrecision->20] 

fails to display the correct x interval when n > 13. The actual range of x is much larger, so that one cannot see the detailed variation of the function within the interval requested. It seems that 10^-n is simply replaced by zero when n > 13, despite the increased WorkingPrecision. How to eliminate this problem?
Leszek

Use ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None} with Plot or use LogLinearPlot vice Plot. In either case the x-axis tick labels will need to be adjusted.

I usually use manual scaling. It's usually faster than figuring out the right scaling function. The domain (input) is plotted as $x_0 + n\cdot\epsilon$, where $x_0$ is the point of central interest and $\epsilon$ is an appropriate scale (usually a power of 10 or of 2, depending on my use-case). By appropriate, I mean such that the plot I wish to construct has $n$ ranging between $\pm10$, more or less, so that the tick marks will be small integers. There's no point in making them the actual values of $x$, imo, since they differ only in the 11th digit (depending on $\epsilon$).
x0 = 1;
n = 20;
eps = 10^-n/10;
Plot[Log[x0 + dx*eps], {dx, -10, 10},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
 AxesLabel -> {Row[{x0, "+", HoldForm[n], "\[Times]", 
     10^Row[{"-", -Log10[eps]}]}]},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
 ]


x0 = 1;
n = 20;
eps = 10^-n/10;
Plot[Log[x0 + dx*eps], {dx, -10, 10},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
   {Table[
     If[dx == 0, {0, "1"}, {dx, HoldForm[1 + #] &@N[dx eps]}],
     {dx, -10, 10, 5}], Automatic}},
 ImageSize -> 360]


If I have trouble evaluating the function to high precision, I may do the following, if efficient enough:
ClearAll[obj];
obj[dx_?NumericQ] := 
  With[{x = x0 + SetPrecision[dx, Infinity] eps}, 
   N[Log[x], 6](*6 accurate digs enough for plotting*)];
Plot[obj[dx], {dx, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {Table[
     If[dx == 0, {0, "1"}, {dx, 
       HoldForm[1 + #] &@N[dx eps]}], {dx, -10, 10, 5}], Automatic}}, 
 ImageSize -> 360]

(*  <same as previous>*)

